# How can we render a single window large dashboard screen which is 7000 px x 2000px using React js

Tags: reactjs

[sample picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcWzS.jpg)I need to build a 7000 px x 2000px dashboard screen. How usually we build these gigantic screens in our local machine without scrollbar(ie, we can traverse from one end to other using mouse drag)

Answer (score 0):

You could attach drag handler to the element like

```
<div onDrag={handleDrag} style={{
   width:'7000px',
   height:'2000px',
   transform:translateX(value +'px') //value calculated when dragging
}}>
</div>
```

and in the `handleDrag` function you could calculate the value for traversing.

use `overflow-x: hidden` on the parent element in order to prevent horizontal scroll.